# Show that all abelian groups of order 21 and 35 are cyclic.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

Show that all abelian groups of order 21 and 35 are cyclic. I have no idea on how to start. Can anyone give some hints?

Comment: Do you know FTFGAG?

Comment: Do you mean fundamental theorem of finite generated abelian group ? I din learn this theorem.

Comment: It's worth noting that the abelian requirement is superfluous when the order is 35. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76112/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-n-35-then-it-is-cyclic).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you need is

- the [Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finitely-generated_abelian_group): *Every abelian group* can be written as the *direct product of cyclic groups*...etc.
- And $\mathbb Z_{mn}$ *is cyclic and isomorphic* to $\mathbb Z_m \times \mathbb Z_n$ if and only if $\gcd(m,n) = 1$.

---

With this, you are equipped to conclude what you need for every abelian group of order 35, 21, respectively.

Note that $\mathbb Z_5 \times \mathbb Z_7 \cong \mathbb Z_{35}$, because $\gcd(5, 7) = 1$.
And it follows that $\mathbb Z_{35}$ is cyclic.

Similarly, you can work with $\mathbb Z_3 \times \mathbb Z_7 \cong \mathbb Z_{21}$ because the $\gcd(3, 7) = 1$. And hence, $\mathbb Z_{21}$ is cyclic

Comment: Does this look familiar, Idonknow?

Comment: I don know the theorem but I do know the second statement. We prove the second statement by defining a map and prove the map is isomorphism right ?

Comment: Exactly. That's really all you need for this, the second statement. Check out the link, but don't try to learn it all in a day.

Comment: Feel free to follow up in a comment here if you want to check anything more out, as you write up the proof/solution.

Comment: :^) nice Amy...

Answer (score 6):

You can do this with elementary tools. Here is a possible plan for an abelian group $G$ of order 21.

1. By Lagrange's theorem, the order of any element is one of 1, 3, 7 or 21.
2. Take an arbitrary element $a \neq 1$. Its order is either 3, 7 or 21. Suppose it is 3 (the case when it is 7 is similar, and if it is 21 then we are done).
3. The quotient group $G/\langle a \rangle $ has order $7$, so in fact $G/\langle a \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_7$. Every element in $\mathbb{Z}_7$ except the identity has order $7$. Then every element in $G - \langle a \rangle$ has order that is divisible by $7$. Then there is an element $b \in G$ of order $7$.
4. So, we have elements $a$ and $b$ of orders $3$ and $7$. It is easy to see that then $G$ is a direct product $G = \langle a \rangle \times \langle b \rangle$, so $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$. It is in fact cyclic, qed.

Comment: If you remove "suppose $G$ is not cyclic" at the top and ",so this is a contradiction." you realize this is really a direct proof. Lagrange's theorem doesn't rely on the group being cyclic, so your proof works out.

Comment: @Peter Yes, it does work out. It didn't work out this way in my original approach, so the proof by contradiction is here for historic reasons )

Comment: My sole point is that it is kinda meaningless to include those phrases, since this is not a proof by contradiction. Moreover, it might give rise to confusion.

Comment: @Peter I see your point, but if I try to rewrite this as a direct proof, then steps 2 and 3 will become messy. In step 2 i'll have to add something like "and if the order of $a$ is 21, we are done". And I'll have to add a similar remark about the order of $b$ in step 3. This will probably look messy. Could you maybe suggest a way to avoid that?

Comment: Oh, now I see the catch, my bad. But still I will try and think something.

Comment: @Peter I've rewritten it as a direct proof, and it looks better, even with those additional remarks. So, thanks for suggesting an improvement to the answer :-)

Comment: And if it's not clear to anyone this exact proof goes through if you replace $3$ with $5$ and $21$ with $35$. Or more notably if you replace $3$ and $7$ with any two distinct primes.

Comment: Does this proof actually rely on it being abelian? If it does could you please clarify which step (or part thereof) doesn't hold if it's non-abelian

Comment: @Alex it relies on abelianness in step 4, in the "easy to see" part. One has to consider products like $a^m b^n$ and use the fact that $(a^m b^n)(a^{m'}b^{n'}) = a^{m + m'} b^{n + n'}$, which is true due to the abelianness. Without abelianness one can construct a semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}_3$ and $\mathbb{Z}_7$ that is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_3 \times \mathbb{Z}_7$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: There are only 2 possible abelian groups of order 21: $\mathbb{Z}_{21}$ and $\mathbb{Z}_3\times\mathbb{Z}_7$. You can show that the latter is cyclic by exhibiting a generator (it's probably the first thing you'll think of); in fact these groups are isomorphic.