# How to tell if an abelian group is cyclic or not?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups

An abelian group is expressed into the canonical form:

$$\bigoplus\mathbb{Z}_{k_i}$$

where $k_i$ are powers of primes. I want to know if the group is cyclic or not.

It seems from what I've read that such a group is cyclic if and only if $\forall i\neq j: \gcd(k_i,k_j)=1$.

I even managed to find [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/321095/43535) that explicitly states this. However the questions and answers that I could find are mainly concerned with the "if" part. I understand that one. But is the "only if" part true? How to prove that the group is not cyclic if some pair of the $k_i$'s are powers of the same prime?

Answer (score 3):

If $\gcd(a,b)=1$ then $\Bbb Z_a\oplus \Bbb Z_b\cong \Bbb Z_{ab}$.
So we can bunch together coprime cyclic factors, and will succeed in getting a cyclic group **unless** we get a pair of factors $\Bbb Z_a\oplus \Bbb Z_b$ with $g=\gcd(a,b)>1$. But in that case $\Bbb Z_a\oplus \Bbb Z_b$
has $g^2$ solutions to $gx=0$, so it isn't cyclic, and neither can any
group containing it be cyclic.

Comment: Or $\Bbb Z_a\oplus \Bbb Z_b$ has exponent $ab/g < ab$ and so is not cyclic.

Comment: Sorry, I must be missing something very basic. I managed to follow the argument all up to "so it isn't cyclic". Yes I see that there are $g^2$ solutions for $gx=0$. How does not being cyclic follow from that?