# Let $G$ be a group of order 35. Show that $G \cong Z_{35}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group of order 35. Show that $G \cong Z_{35}$

Now, I am going to assume that this is a LaGrange based question. Also, I know that in order to be isomorphic, it must be one to one and onto.

Comment: Do you know the Sylow theorems?

Comment: @MattSamuel, Im just learning them. I havnt really worked problems using them yet

Comment: Try looking [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/76112/if-g-is-a-group-of-order-n-35-then-it-is-cyclic). I believe this is a duplicate.

Comment: @Cele Be careful about pronouns.  When you say "it must be one to one and onto" you should be very clear about what "it" refers to (a homomorphism)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\#G = 5.7$ Let ${S}_{5}$ denote the Sylow 5-subgroup and ${S}_{7}$ the Sylow 7-subgroup.
Now $${S}_{5} \cap {S}_{7}$$ is a subgroup and the number of elements in it divides 5 and 7 (Lagrange). So $$ \#{S}_{5} \cap {S}_{7} = 1$$
Then $$ \#{S}_{5}{S}_{7} = \frac{\#{S}_{5}.\#{S}_{7}}{ \#{S}_{5} \cap {S}_{7}}=5.7=35$$
Because ${S}_{5}{S}_{7} \subset G$ and $\#{S}_{5}{S}_{7} = \#G$ it follows that: $$G = {S}_{5}{S}_{7}$$ By Sylow's second theorem (because 5 and 7 are primes): 
 ${S}_{5}$ is the only Sylow 5-subgroup of $G$. The same for ${S}_{7}$. So $${S}_{5},{S}_{7} \triangleleft G$$ 
This are all the requirements that needed to be true for a group to be isomorphic with the direct product: ${S}_{5} \times {S}_{7}$. Since ${S}_{5}$ and ${S}_{5}$ are cyclic (number of elements is prime) it follows that ${S}_{5} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{5}$. Same for ${S}_{7}$. So ${S}_{7} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{7}$. Because 5 and 7 have no common divisors other than 1 it follows: $$\mathbb{Z}_{5} \times \mathbb{Z}_{7} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{35}$$ And so $$G \cong {S}_{5} \times {S}_{7} \cong \mathbb{Z}_{35}$$

Comment: in regard to your notation, I am assuming that # refers to the order??

Comment: Yes the number of elements of G. Sorry I always use $\#$ forgot that it might be unclear.

Comment: I am assuming that right above your last 'paragraph,' that is suppose to be $S_5,S_7 \triangleleft G$?

Comment: Yeah indeed, my mistake

Comment: Hi what theorem are you using when you say that these "are all the requirements needed for a group to be isomorphic with the direct product"?

Comment: I don't know the name, but the isomorphism is given by
$\sigma: S_5 \times S_7 \rightarrow G: (g,h) \mapsto gh$. First show commutativity: $\sigma(g,h)=gh =hg$. To see this, let $x \in G$ such that $gh = hg x$. Then $x = g^{-1}h^{-1}gh \in S_5 \cap S_7$, which can be seen since both subgroups are normal. But then $x = e$. The same argument shows that $\sigma$ is injective. Now use that $|S_5 \times S_7| = 35 = |G|$ to see that $\sigma$ is also surjective.